# Laravel 4 filters and view composers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've created myself an filter and a View composer. First of all here are the codes:

my admin filter:

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) 
    {
        $roles = Auth::user()->role;

        if ($roles == '5') 
        {
            return Redirect::to('news/index')->with('roles', $roles);
        } 
    } 
    else 
    {
        return View::make('errors.401');
    }
});
```

and my view composer (it's in global.php):

```
// View composer
View::composer(array('common.menu_addition','common.base_errors'), function($view)
{
    if (Auth::check()) 
    {
        $roles = Auth::user()->type;
        if ($roles == '5') 
        {
            $view->with('roles', $roles);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $view;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('news/index');
    }
});
```

So it doesn't work. I want to access some pages with my admin account (that has role equals to 5, column 'role' in database). I made a group in my routes, but when I try to access a page it redirects me to my news/index page.

How can I set it to make any page that needs an admin role viewable?

I also used Jeffrey Way's generator to make an scaffold, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I do something very similar in my application, but after some trial and error myself I figured the best way to authenticate users and admins was to have two separate filters. So, here is what I do:

I have an `auth` filter that simply logs a user in -

```
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('login');
});
```

In addition to this, I have an `auth.admin` filter that checks for the logged in Users role:

```
Route::filter('auth.admin', function() {
    if(Auth::user()->userprofile->security_level < 4) {
        return Redirect::route('projects.home');
    }
});
```

One caveat to remember is that to not use the `auth.admin` filter, standalone, in your routes. Will throw an error when the user is not logged in. You can do something like:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('user', array('as' => 'user.home', 'uses' => 'UsersController@index'));});
}

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|auth.admin'), function() {
    Route::get('user/create', array('as' => 'user.create', 'uses' => 'UsersController@create'));
});
```

With this setup, add the pages you want only your admin to access to the latter routing group with `auth` and `auth.admin`.

Now, with this setup, you don't need to check for logic in your composer. Ideally, your routing (or your controller, based on what your argument is) should handle your routing logic.

You can rewrite your composer like this:

```
View::composer( array( 'common.menu_addition','common.base_errors' ), function( $view ) {

    // get all categories using the category model
    $categories = Category::all();
    $view->with( 'categories', $categories );

});
```

A composer is used to pass the same set of data or to carry out the same set of tasks for a set of views.

I am sure this will sort you out ;)